# IE8 position relative negative value issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I'm building a website http://inbrackets.dk/marek/ that looks awfully in IE8 and I dont really know how to fix it.

The problem is with the pictures on the front page. To overlap them a little I used:

```
.marek-photo,
.aref-photo,
.truc-photo {
    left: 80px;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}
.aref-photo {
    left: -30px;
}
.truc-photo {
    left: -120px;
}
.photos {
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #003D3D;
}
```

I know, that this issue isn't new, but I still couldn't find a proper solution.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You are using CSS media queries to change the size of the three images to 33%.  IE8- does not support media queries (other than `print`, I believe).  Add a general screen rule to set the widths to 33% or use JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, adding the width did not fix the problem. Any other ideas, please?

Comment: Isn't the negative value left:-30px; that causes the problem? In all browsers the pictures stand next to each other, while in IE8 and lower, they tile up one above another.

Answer (score 0):

try inserting the modernizr library in your page http://modernizr.com

Comment: The website is using modernizr library. Yet, it doesn't help to solve the problem.